# MongoDB is slow after deleting large data

Tags: performance, mongodb

We have large collection 172GB( 30M records), 72GB(60M records). We have deleted 14M records from each collection and now database is slow for insert/update/select. Can we reorganize collection like other relation database? If yes, how.

Answer (score 2):

Try [compact](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/compact/) the collection. If it is in live production, you'll want to do this on a secondary. After compact is done on secondary, let it catch up to primary, then let primary stepdown and the compacted secondary becomes the new primary.

However, make sure you have enough room to do compaction. Compact requires at least 1:1 free space ratio. In your case, you'll need 172GB of free space to complete that first collection.

Another option is to export data with [mongodump](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) or [snapshot](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-with-filesystem-snapshots/), then [dropDatabase](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/dropDatabase/) to free up space, then [mongorestore](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/) from dumped bson file or restore snapshot.

I personally recommend mongodump->mongorestore option, as it will rebuild the database and give it a clean start. Additional read [here](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Taking-backups-and-importing-data-for-mongodb)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I can't use mongodump, because it takes 2-3 days for this data size. I will try compact. Do you have any idea how long compact takes for 172GB data?

Comment: Far less than dumping and restoring. Also, since you are doing it on a secondary first, it should not impact your application. The step down will make the database unavailable during the elections which should not take more than 2 seconds. Consider switching to SSDs.